# Angular. Replace word in string with component

Tags: angular, angular9

Angular 9. I'm new with it. I have a string (named as `message`) and users array (as `users`) in `TextInMessageComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from 'app/models/user';

@Component({
  selector: '.text-in-message',
  templateUrl: './text-in-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['text-in-message.component.scss'],
})
export class TextInMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() users: User[];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  private escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  }
}
```

Also I have `UserInMessageComponent` component to bind some logic (onclick etc.):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from 'app/models/user';

@Component({
  selector: '.user-in-message',
  template: `{{ user.username }}`,
  styleUrls: ['user-in-message.component.scss'],
})
export class UserInMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() user: User;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  @HostBinding('style.color') color: string;
  @HostBinding('class.font-1') isFont1: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-2') isFont2: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-3') isFont3: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-4') isFont4: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-5') isFont5: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-6') isFont6: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-7') isFont7: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.font-8') isFont8: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.color = this.pickHlsColor(this.user.nameColor);
    for (let i = 1; i < 9; i += 1) {
      const propname = `isFont{i}`;
      this[propname] = this.pickFont(i);
    }
  }

  pickFont(type): boolean {
    return this.user.nameFont === `font-${type}`;
  }

  pickHlsColor(value) {
    const n = value.split(',');
    return `hsl(${n[0]}, ${n[1]}%, ${n[2]}%)`;
  }
}
```

I need to replace each `username` in `message` from `TextInMessageComponent` by correct `UserInMessageComponent`. But I really don't know how to google it :(

I tried:

```
export class TextInMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() users: User[];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users
      .sort((a, b) => b.username.length - a.username.length)
      .map((recepient, index) => {
        const { username } = recepient;
        const escapedString = this.escapeRegExp(username);
        const regexp = new RegExp(escapedString, 'g');
        this.message = this.message.replace(regexp, `%%s${index}%%`);
        return recepient;
      })
      .forEach((recepient, index) => {
        const searchString = `%%s${index}%%`;
        const regexp = new RegExp(searchString, 'g');
        const userReplacement = `<span class="user-in-message" [user]="${recepient}">Loadin user-in-message componen...</span>`;
        this.message = this.message.replace(regexp, userReplacement);
      });
  }

  private escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  }
}
```

But not working :(

My output in html page now is:

```
Chuck Norris: <span class="user-in-message" [user]="[object Object]">Loading user-in-message componen...</span>, I've heard Chuck Norris was going to be a playable character in SSBB. His hammer-using animation would be him moving the hammer in a full circle with only his left pinky. It turns out that he is stronger than that.
```

`span class="user-in-message"` should be correct component

Comment: can you please provide a working demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: This seems to be more of a javascript related question rather than an Angular related question as what you are asking is to replace usernames in message. Please add an example of what your `users` and `message` contains.

Comment: I need to replace selected with regexp words by correct components. please look on lowest code

Comment: what is error and what is not working ? make it simple to explain more/

Comment: question updated

Answer (score -1):

The correct technique in this case is to use Component Factory. Each chunk of the string will be separated component.